# What does gws_rd=cr in the URL indicate?

Tags: google-search, url

On opening Google.com, `gws_rd=cr` is added to the URL. This has been happening only for the past day or so.

What does this indicate?

Why did this start showing up recently? I have been using the same browser for years.

Answer (score 13):

it means Google web server(gws) getting redirected (rd)by country(cr).
i.e a country other than US.

Comment: What changed one or two days ago that it started showing? i have been using Chromium for years

Comment: Nothing changed, google constantly seeks out better ways to strengthen its tracking, this could be part of it, may also be temp. no official word from google out yet about this...may be wait a few days, questions about this is popping out everywhere on the web now. But be content that its not a virus of some kind as was previously being assumed... The thing is that in last 3 or 4 days, google has added and sorted out few glitches on youtube section and also trying to link it with g+. The most probable answer is the new chrome 28v rolled out 3 days ago.

Comment: I am getting the same URL in IE9 Incog as well.

Comment: Then no need to worry, it is just a redirect string...in case you type only 'google' or 'google.com' instead of your own country domain, it redirects to gws...I am not a vivid developer so have less knowledge in this regard. For eg, type google.co.uk or google.co.us (country code), it won't show gws...

Comment: If you wish to access original google type - google.com/webhp?hl=en

Comment: Got it - gws (google web server)_rd(redirect)=cr(country)

Comment: @James - you should update your answer rather than posting comments